# How to prevent code the being send duplicate email in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a code on my website to send an email when a user clicks on a button. For some reasons, the code started sending an enormous number of duplicate emails. Actually, it stopped sending when it reached the GoDaddy daily limit, ie. 5000 emails!!!

Is there any way to prevent this situation? Do SMTP timeout helps in this situation?

```
    try
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("sg2nlvphout-v01.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net", 25);
        client.EnableSsl = false;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "password");
        MailMessage msgobj = new MailMessage();
        msgobj.To.Add(email);
        msgobj.From = new MailAddress("email@domain.com");
        msgobj.Subject = "Subject";
        msgobj.Body = body;
        AlternateView altView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgobj.Body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

        msgobj.AlternateViews.Add(altView);

        client.Send(msgobj);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a technical issue? Isn't a spammer/bot or something like that?

Comment: Are you asking on how to prevent users from spamming you?

Comment: @Julian I don't think so. Most probably, it's a technical issue

Comment: @Fluous No, I'm asking about how to prevent my code from sending duplicate emails.

Comment: @BlockchainExpert I think your problem might somewhere else than in this code. I see no reason why this code would execute 5000 times, unless it is requested to do so (by another part of your application). Could you extend your question with the code from the front-end, API or controller that receives the request and the rest of the function in which this code is placed (and anything else in between).

Comment: add to your code/page a captcha !

Comment: So in actual fact you don't have any idea why it sent so many emails, you're just guessing. Follow the prior advice and add a captcha

Comment: Why do you have an empty catch block in your code? Don't you care if something goes wrong while handling this request?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
try
    {
        bool flag = false;
if(!flag)
{        
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("sg2nlvphout-v01.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net", 25);
        client.EnableSsl = false;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "password");
        MailMessage msgobj = new MailMessage();
        msgobj.To.Add(email);
        msgobj.From = new MailAddress("email@domain.com");
        msgobj.Subject = "Subject";
        msgobj.Body = body;
        AlternateView altView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgobj.Body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

        msgobj.AlternateViews.Add(altView);

        client.Send(msgobj);
        flag = true;
}
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```